# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (400,) (2,)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, callable

For some reason I'm getting a module object is not callable error on this code...and I don't really get why?

```
def func (t,a,x):
return
`plt.plot(t,(exp(a*t))*x(), label="lalala")`
```

....and the Traceback

`plt.plot(t,(exp(a*t))*x(), label="lalala")
  TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`

after changing x() to x

```
x=np.array([1,100])
t=np.linspace(1,10,400)
def func (t,a,x):
    return plt.plot(t,(exp(a*t))*x, label="lalala")
```

Now I get:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (400,) (2,)

The goal is to sketch a graphic with the function:

`exp(a*t)*x` over the time `t...=>y= exp(a*t)*x`

on the y-axis and t is the x-axis.

`a` is the hole time constant, `t(1,10,400)` and `x(1,100)` changes.

Comment: Please give us information what are `exp(a*t)` and `x()`

Comment: Please edit your question with information with your most recent error message (instead of putting it in an answer) and give some information about what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: ... so there are 400 time points between 1 and 10 (inclusive). You have two different values of `x` you're interested in?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to know for sure what you're after, but from your edits it seems you have two values of `x` you want to plot the graph of y = x.exp(a.t) for over the time range `t=np.linspace(1,10,400)`. In which case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = 2
x = np.array([1,100])
t=np.linspace(1,10,400)
def func(t, a, z):
    return z * np.exp(a * t)

plt.plot(t,func(t, a, x[0]))
plt.plot(t,func(t, a, x[1]))
```

You're getting the error because `x` is an array of two values and NumPy doesn't (without some help) know how to "broadcast" these two values in relation to your time array. If you want `func` to produce an array of shape `(2,400)` in response to the input `x`, use `np.newaxis` to create the missing second axis in the `x` array:

```
func(t, a, x[:,np.newaxis])
```